# Dynamic links with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, dynamic

this is my problem.I have a JSP. I want to create a hyperlink dynamically with Javascript. I want to add the text from an `input` in HTML and use it to pass it as a parameter in my URL:

```
<form name="test">
<P>Enter search: <input type="text" name="searchName"><BR><BR>
<input type="Button" Value="" onclick="location.href='search.jsp?typeOfSearch=" + JavaScriptFunction( that returns the String from searchName ) ' " >
</P>
</FORM>
```

I cant seem to add a JS function to the "onclick" string. I ve tried with HREF from an anchor but I cant make it work. And I ve also tried just putting a JS function like this:

```
<a href="MyJSfunction( that returns the entire URL ) " >  hyperlink</a>
```

and also it does not work. I ve tried like a million diferent things and I still cant pass dynamic parameters from one JSP to another.

Any help would be very good! ...

Comment: The double quote following `typeOfSeach=` closes your onclick attribute.  That would need to be a single quote.  You have an extra single quote after your function call which should be removed.  To get the quotes right on your onclick attribute, you need: `onclick="location.href='search.jsp?typeOfSearch='+SomeFunction(someParameter)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't too concerned about security, a simple HTML form should work.

```
<form action="Your URL Here">
    <input type="text" value="" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/VfuT4/

Comment: What's the security risk?  Or, how would using JavaScript improve security?

Comment: I suppose if you were concerned with security, you would use post rather than get. In that case you would add a `method="post"` attribute to the form.

Comment: I m not really an expert on security issues, or any kind of expert for that matter... but for now I m not worried about security. Im just glad it works.

Comment: oh I see. So whats the big diference between "post" and "get" ? I m kind of a newbie at this stuff...

Comment: Post doesn't reveal the payload in the location query string. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: @user3258537 If we have helped you, please choose one of the answers as your accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No JavaScript required.  Just set your form method and action, use a submit button, and rename your input field:

```
<form name="test" method="GET" action="search.jsp">
    <p>
        Enter search: <input type="text" name="typeOfSearch" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="Submit" Value="Go" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**Edit:** But, if you are just curious how to do it with JavaScript, form elements all have a `form` property.  Form elements are accessible from the form by name.  So, you can use `this.form.searchName.value` to get the value of the `searchName` field in the same form as your button:

```
<input type="Button" Value=""
    onclick="location.href='search.jsp?typeOfSearch=' + this.form.searchName.value;" />
```

**Edit:** The trouble you are having with your current code may be because you have the quotes wrong.  Change the double quote at the end of `typeOfSearch="` to a single quote: `typeOfSearch='`.  Remove the single quote following your function call:

```
<input type="Button" value=""
    onclick="location.href='search.jsp?typeOfSearch=' + JavaScriptFunction()" />
```

Comment: I ve tried both ways: "this.form.searchName.value" and with JavaScript function. the first one worked , the second no. If you have any idea on why the second one doesnt work I would apreciate it. 
but anyway , thanks a lot. the first one does work and I was having a lot of troubles getting this done.

Comment: @user3258537 - Either of the two JavaScript ways are wonky.  Use the Non-JavaScript way.  If your JavaScript function isn't working, I wouldn't know why without seeing the actual function code.

Comment: ok! I got it working now. I was making a mistake on my JS function... thanks again.